# Как воспользоваться двумя сервисами в одном компоненте? Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

В данном компоненте я создаю модальное окно используя DialogService. После подтверждения вызывается метод confirm, где вызывается метод setName сервиса SocketService. При запуске приложения появляется ошибка

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setName' of undefined

Как воспользоваться двумя сервисами, если в конструкторе можно прописать только один?
Код компонента:

```
export interface ConfirmModel{
    title: string;
    content: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirm',
  templateUrl: './confirm.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirm.component.css']
})
export class ConfirmComponent extends DialogComponent<ConfirmModel, boolean> implements ConfirmModel{
  title: string;
  content: string;
  edited: boolean = true;
  name: string = '';
  private socketService: SocketService;

  constructor(dialogService: DialogService){ 
    super(dialogService);
  }
  confirm(){
    this.result = true;
    this.socketService.setName(this.name);
    this.close();
  }
  close(){
    this.edited = false;
  }
}
```

Код SocketService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketService {

    private host: string="http://192.168.0.106:8080";
    private socket: any = io(this.host);

    sendMessage(message){
        this.socket.emit('callDriver', message);    
    }
    setName(name){
        this.socket.emit('setName', name);
    }
    getName(){
        let observable = new Observable<string>(observer => {
          this.socket.on('getName', (name) => {
            observer.next(name);    
          });
            return () => {
             this.socket.disconnect();
            };  
          })     
            return observable;
        }     

      getMessages() {
        let observable = new Observable(observer => {
          this.socket.on('sendToDriver', (message) => {
            observer.next(message);    
          });
            return () => {
             this.socket.disconnect();
            };  
          })     
            return observable;
        }  

  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: `Как воспользоваться двумя сервисами, если в конструкторе можно прописать только один?` - с чего вы это взяли? 

Comment: Вы можете инжектить несколько сервисов. Кто вам не разрешает несколько использовать?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko доки ж по азам читать никто не любит, зато всегда беремся за изучение всяких либ и прочее 

Comment: @overthesanity некогда доки читать - надо работать! Можете написать ответ, в котором будет показано как инжектить сервис не через конструктор компонента? Есть что-то типа `ComponentFactoryResolver` для сервисов?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko `некогда доки читать - надо работать` - дело то святое, но сами ж знаете, без документации далеко не уедешь, как говорит мой СТО - RTFM  есть `Injector` для сервисов, но человеку достаточно прописать сервис в конструкторе)

Comment: Только сейчас увидел свою ошибку, неправильно прописывал сервис

Comment: @overthesanity Человеку достаточно, а мне было бы очень интересно посмотреть, как это сделать не через конструктор компонента.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko `constructor(injector: Injector) { this.socketService = injector.get(SocketService); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы не можете инжектить больше одного сервиса в конструкторе, то можете создать инстанс этого сервиса сами!

```
export interface ConfirmModel{
    title: string;
    content: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirm',
  templateUrl: './confirm.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirm.component.css']
})
export class ConfirmComponent extends DialogComponent<ConfirmModel, boolean> implements ConfirmModel{
  title: string;
  content: string;
  edited: boolean = true;
  name: string = '';
  private socketService: SocketService;

  constructor(injector: Injector, dialogService: DialogService){
    super(dialogService);
    this.socketService = injector.get(SocketService);
  }
  confirm(){
    this.result = true;
    this.socketService.setName(this.name);
    this.close();
  }
  close(){
    this.edited = false;
  }
}
```